# Cucumber: Is it possible to only run .feature files but not scenario-examples in parallel with cli execution?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am using Cucumber (6.8.1) with Selenium (4.7.2).

I want to run multiple .feature files containing a scenario or scenario outline with the parameter "--threads 5". All the .feature files are in the same directory.

Is it possible to run the .feature files in parallel and not the scenario outline examples?

The scenario outline examples must be run sequentially.

I am running the Tests via CLI. The Docu states "[...] The --threads option needs to be set to a value greater than 1 to run in parallel. When the parallel mode is used, the scenarios and rows in a scenario outline will be run in multiple threads."